# Date.prototype.toISOString() not returning correct result

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, toisostring

From description of this function at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO
>   format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 characters long:
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ. The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as
>   denoted by the suffix "Z".

It should return 24 characters long all the time. Check the following example:

```
var d = new Date('08AUG20144');
d.toISOString();
```

Returns `+020144-08-08T04:00:00.000Z` which is 27 characters long. Any reason?

Comment: `08AUG20144` is not a valid date, the year has 5 digits :-)

Comment: @GiladArtzi - years can't have five digits? You mean we have to start preparing for all the code that will break because of the Y10K problem?

Comment: "To represent years before 0000 or after 9999, the standard also permits the expansion of the year representation but only by prior agreement between the sender and the receiver. An expanded year representation [±YYYYY] must have an agreed-upon number of extra year digits beyond the four-digit minimum, and it must be prefixed with a + or − sign instead of the more common AD/BC (or BCE/CE) notation; by convention 1 BC is labelled +0000, 2 BC is labeled -0001, and so on." – https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years

Comment: …concluding that the MDN documentation should be fixed, not the implementation.

Comment: Firstly, you should not expect any browser to correctly parse '08AUG20144'. Secondly, there is only one authoritative reference for ECMAScript: [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), not MDN.

Comment: @RobG try it in chrome/firefox console, it does parse it properly.

Comment: @vimdude—the issue isn't whether one or two browsers parse it correctly, but whether *all browsers in use* parse it correctly. And don't just think of common desktop and mobile browsers, but any browser enable device like TVs, automotive and aircraft entertainment systems.

Answer (score 4):

The ECMAScript specification [says about *Extended Years*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-extended-years):

> ECMAScript requires the ability to specify 6 digit years (extended
>   years); approximately 285,426 years, either forward or backward, from
>   01 January, 1970 UTC. To represent years before 0 or after 9999, ISO
>   8601 permits the expansion of the year representation, but only by
>   prior agreement between the sender and the receiver. In the simplified
>   ECMAScript format such an **expanded year representation shall have 2
>   extra year digits and is always prefixed with a + or – sign**. The year
>   0 is considered positive and hence prefixed with a + sign.

[I've adapted the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString$compare?locale=en-US&to=1068422&from=980263).

Comment: Which highlights that ECMA-262 is the normative reference, not MDN.